# Best alternative to using the global variable in this code

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

Since I started programming, I seem to be aiming towards global variables, and find it difficult to work without them, and found it especially difficult here with a recursive function. Can someone help me with this code to make it global variable free? Also, is there a reference which can help change the method of thinking so I do not end up feeling the need for them? I feel something in the way I think about code needs to change, but I don't know what.

```js
var res = [];

function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  func(arr);
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}

steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);

function func(array){
  for (var i=0; i<array.length ; i++){
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])){
      func(array[i]);
    }
    else {
      res.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the usual name for this is *flatten*.

Comment: Just returning the value from the function func() can do your work.. I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the result array as an argument, since arrays and object are passed by reference in JS.

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  var res = [];
  func(arr, res);
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}

steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);

function func(array, res){
  for (var i=0; i<array.length ; i++){
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])){
      func(array[i], res);
    }
    else {
      res.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, thank you. It explained it in the simplest of terms, without changing, just helping me change the way I think.

Answer (score 3):

Just declare the variable inside the function, and return it at the end. Handle recursive calls appropriately.

```js
function flatten(array){
  var res = [];
  for (var item of array) {
    if (Array.isArray(item))
      res.push(...flatten(item));
    else
      res.push(item);
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(flatten([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```

This does not behave exactly like your code, but it's what one would probably expect.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a single function, which iterates and collect the data and returns only the part collected data.

```js
function steamrollArray(array) {
    var result = [];  
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            result = result.concat(steamrollArray(array[i]));
        } else {
            result.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could nest functions:

```
function steamrollArray(inputArray) {
  var res = [];
  var process = function(arrayToProcess){
    for (var i=0; i<arrayToProcess.length ; i++){
      if (Array.isArray(arrayToProcess[i])){
        process(arrayToProcess[i]);
      }
      else {
        res.push(arrayToProcess[i]);
      }
    }
  };
  process(inputArray);
  return res;
}

steamrollArray([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Comment: I love this solution too! Would anyone be able to comment which is better practice in this case? Nest functions or sending the result as another parameter to the function itself?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `reduce` and the [Spread operator (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), you can even solve your problem without any variable assignment:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    if (Array.isArray(c)) {
      return [...p, ...flatten(c)];
    }
    return [...p, c];
  }, [])
}

console.log(flatten([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the true recursion:

```js
console.log(f([1, {}, [3, [[4]]]]));

function f(xs){
  if (xs.length === 0) return xs;

  return (Array.isArray(xs[0]) ? f(xs[0]) : [xs[0]]).concat(f(xs.splice(1)));
}
```